# Powershell install all vscode extensions on a new PC

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I have the current script which installs chocolatey on a new computer and installs all my main applications and confirms theyre up to date:

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Install chocolatey packet manager
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; Invoke-Expression ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install needed packages (these can be changed to suit your needs)
choco install brave discord microsoft-teams microsoft-office-deployment vscode visualstudio2019community sql-server-management-studio tableau-desktop git -y

# Confirm all software is up to date
choco update all -y
```

I was wondering if there is a way i can at the end of this script be able to install all my vscode extensions as well onto a new pc (windows).

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to sync settings between computers. There are probably extensions for that (if VS Code doesn't do it natively).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks for the comment, i managed to figure out a short way with a powershell script

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone needs it, there is a cool solution written in PowerShell. [This is the project on Github.](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell) / [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Install-VSCode/1.2/Content/Install-VSCode.ps1)

In summary, VS-Code, and extensions are installed like this :

```
Install-Script Install-VSCode; Install-VSCode.ps1 -AdditionalExtensions 'ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions', 'ms-python.python'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to install an extension in VS Code via PS:

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" -ArgumentList "--install-extension","ms-vscode.powershell","--force" -wait
```

You will have to set this value in your `settings.json` if you want it to run without cert errors:

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL"": false
```